# Getting aggregated share in R

Tags: r, aggregation

I have a data set that I need to analyze in R. A simplified version of it would be like this

```
SessionNo.  Objects       OtherColumns
    A          2               .
    A          3
    B          4
    C          1
    D          2
    D          1
    D          2
    D          3
    E          5
```

here each sessionno. represents one session of a broswer but due to the relation with other columns in the data it is aggregated like shown. So, Session 1 is now fragmented into two rows etc. What I need to find is the avg. number of objects downloaded per session (or any other statistics for no. of rows in each session). So, how do I count the no of objects for each session in R. Here, 5 objects in session A, 4 in session B, 8 in session D etc.

I guess one way would be to sum the whole Objects column and count the no. of unique session numbers in SessionNo. But I guess it would be more of a general solution if I could group the unique session number with the total number of objects aggregated in it? Any suggestions on how to accomplish that in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this might help:

```
tapply(df$Objects, df$SessionNo., sum)
```

Comment: +1 since `aggregate` is an overshoot here and plyr is slow.

Comment: -1 That can't possibly work unless you make the components of the data frame visible (using say `with()`, or refer to the explicitly via, e.g., `df$Objects` where `df` is the op's data frame.

Comment: @mbq: why is `aggregate()` an "overshoot here"? It seems very natural as it returns for you a DF with the unique `SessionNo.` plus the sum for each. `tapply()` just gives the sums.

Comment: @Gavin: You´re right, i´ve edited my post.

Comment: @EDi +1 following edit

Comment: I would have opted for by().

Comment: @Gavin Subjective thing; I like the simplicity of `tapply`, yet of course `subset` will be the way to go to make it the fastest possible in plain R.

Comment: @Roman Add an answer, it will be a nice pool.

Answer (score 8):

The function that is specifically designed for this task is ave(). By default it returned the mean within a group and returns a vector of the same length as the two input arguments. It is designed to fill in columns of either means or deviations from means. If this is in a dataframe with name "tst":

```
> tst$tmn <- with(tst, ave(Objects, SessionNo.))
> tst$devmn <- tst$Objects- with(tst, ave(Objects, SessionNo.))
> tst
  SessionNo. Objects tmn devmn
1          A       2 2.5  -0.5
2          A       3 2.5   0.5
3          B       4 4.0   0.0
4          C       1 1.0   0.0
5          D       2 2.0   0.0
6          D       1 2.0  -1.0
7          D       2 2.0   0.0
8          D       3 2.0   1.0
9          E       5 5.0   0.0
```

Comment: if you are using `with()`, then go the whole hog and use `within()` here --- gets rid of more `$`. Your first line could be, `tst <- within(tst, tmn <- ave(Objects, SessionNo.))` whilst your second line could be `tst <- within(tst, devmn <- Objects - ave(Objects, SessionNo.))`. Note that the second line contains two modifications as the whole thing can be inside `with()` or `within()`.

Answer (score 3):

If I am reading your question correctly, something like the following should do it:

`aggregate(x$Objects,by=list(x$SessionNo.),sum)`

where `x` is the data frame containing your data. This will give you, for each unique session number, the sum of the object counts.

You can of course substitute other functions (including your own) on place of the `sum`.

Answer (score 3):

I personally like using the plyr and or reshape packages for tasks like this. If you're just starting with R, I would highly recommend getting to know them well. They've solved nearly all of my data manipulation tasks.

```
ddply(df, .(sessionNo.) function(x) data.frame(
obj.count=sum(Objects)
))
```

OR, cast

```
colnames(df[1:2]) <- c("variable","value")
cast(df[1:2], variable ~ value, sum)
```

Comment: I think the colnames line above needs to be rewritten as `colnames(df)[1:2] <- c("variable","value")`?

Answer (score 3):

I often use `by`, which is a wrapper around `tapply`. Result is a list with a weee different print method compared to `tapply`.

```
df <- data.frame(SessionNo. = sample(x = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
                size = 20, replace = TRUE,
                prob = c(0.05, 0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.05)),
        Objects = sample(x = 1:5, size = 20, replace = TRUE))

df.out <- by(data = df$Objects, INDICES = df$SessionNo.,
        FUN = mean, simplify = FALSE)
head(df.out)
$A
[1] 3

$B
[1] 1

$C
[1] 3.222222

$D
[1] 3.833333

$E
[1] 1
```

Comment: Is there a difference if i give the argument "simplify = FALSE" to tapply()?

Comment: Try it, I've provided a full working example. :) You will see the difference if you use str(df.out) on both instances.